# Auto resizing is not working for view contents in xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS. I have created one xib with many controls like textfields and buttons, they are working proper in 3.5 inch screen but not working in 4 inch screen, its not resizing. 
I tried auto resizing mask and set all auto sizing values but its not working for 4 inch screen in iOS. 
I have xcode 5.0.2 version and working on iOS-7.

Comment: Can you show what you've done so we can understand without knowing how can we help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to set auto resizing mask for the whole container. check it please.

Answer (score 0):

```
     self.yourViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue